# Прикрепить toDataURL к mailto

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

Пытаюсь прикрепить вложение из `canvas.toDataURL()` к `mailto`. Gmail открывается, заполняются тема и тело письма, но вложения нет. Есть варианты, как это сделать?

Код:

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

imageData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

var recipient = "*****@gmail.com";

var emailSubject = "Снимок с веб-камеры";

var emailBody = "Привет, прикрепляю снимок с веб-камеры.";

var intent = "mailto:" + encodeURIComponent(recipient) + "?attachment=" + encodeURIComponent(imageData) + "&subject=" + encodeURIComponent(emailSubject) + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(emailBody);     

window.location.href = intent;
```

Перепробовал все. Отправлял чисто `imageData` и т.д. Не работает.